# Removing negative values from DEM using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, dem

i'm using (ArcGIS 10.1) and i want to remove a negative values from DTM in order to keep just a ground topographic surface.

Answer (score 3):

I would point out that, if your terrain dips below sea-level, negative values do represent real elevation values. You did not state if you wanted to set these values to a uniform value (eg., 0) or to NoData. Removing data is different than recoding it.

This can easily be accomplished in the raster calculator using a Con or SetNull.

To set negative values to a uniform value,

```
Con("elev" < 0, 0, "elev")
```

Or, to set negative values to NoData

```
SetNull("elev" < 0, "elev")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this elsewhere which worked a treat.

```
If your raster layername is RasterA, then try (RasterA@1 >= 0) * RasterA@1
```

Comment: Your answer works in QGIS but the question is about ArcGIS.